# Include findstr output which contains SP name in sqlcmd

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd, findstr

How should i include the output of a findstr which retrieves me the name of the stored proc in sqlcmd?

```
@ECHO OFF    
FOR %%f IN ( *.sql) DO (
var xyz = echo %%f | findstr "^test*"
sqlcmd -d databaseX -S server -e -i xyz
)
```

where xyz will evaluate to testStoredProc1.sql, testStoredProc2.sql and so on.
These stored procs have update/insert and select statement
How can i capture the value of xyz and pipe it to sqlcmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off


for  %%f in (test*.sql) do (

  sqlcmd -d databaseX -S server -e -i %%f

)
```

NOT TESTED!

For further information check [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) , [SET](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) ,[DelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: I am getting this error on execution The following usage of the path operator in batch-paramete
substitution is invalid: %~ff"') do set "xyz=%%X"

Comment: @Eve - aah yes.Needs double `%`.Fixed now.

Comment: I am running into an error again. Sqlcmd: '-i': Missing argument. Enter '-?' for help. Seems like it does not identify !xyz!

Comment: @Eve - can you include in your question an example .sql file and to clarify what the string that should be extracted looks like?

Comment: @Eve so you want to filter files that start with `test` ?

Comment: Yes. Only files that start with test